# Simple JDBC connection test with JUnit

Tags: java, testing, jdbc, junit

I want simple test for JDBC connection, I don't use framework, only JDBC and JUnit. Can I perform this test with JUnit? I have no idea how to even test loading driver, please give me some example of connection test.

Connection client:

```
package newpackage.db;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class SqlConnection {
    private Connection con;
    private String name;
    private String url;
    private String password;
    private String driver;

    public SqlConnection() {
        this.name = "root";
        this.password = "12345";
        this.url = "";
        this.driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SqlConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Test case:

```
public void testDriverManager() {
    SqlConnection conClient = new SqlConnection();
    assertEquals(conClient.getConnection(),...);
    or
    assertTrue(conClient.getConnection(),...);
}
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: What is the point of your test (in other words what do you want to test here)

Comment: The point is to check is driver loaded properly, I just try to cover all db stuff with tests to ensure that everything works right from the driver loading to all queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you can follow this guide for the drivermanager in order to establish a connection.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html

The best test for a connection is reading some basic stuff from your database. E.g. select 1 from dual

Be aware that this test requires a running database! Keep the amount of these integrative tests low, as they do not scale well and require a certain environment given. It makes continuous integration on e.g. Hudson kind of more difficult, as you will have to install a database on all continuous integration server nodes and keep it running.

Comment: Do you suggest to perform one SELECT query and then run a test. Which will compare like: asserEquals(selectedInfo, realDataFromDB); in string type for example?

Comment: No, the select  I mentioned I'd rather for testing the sanity of the connection. It's a statement that you'd also use to test a connection before returning it from a connection pool or similar. Just open a connection, run the statement and check that no exception was thrown. There is no need to check that mySQL really returned 1.

Comment: I catch it, so what tool I need for serious testing queries or the exception handling is enough?

Comment: http://www.dbunit.org/intro.html enables you to do real database testing. It lets you insert xml based test data and perform some operations on it. After each test case, it rolls back your changes. Very cool framework. Anyway, one could write a book about database testing. I suggest you give it a try and come back with more detailed questions.